# Create a single for loop from multiple for loops in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am working with some data that I have collected. Usually my work involves multiple levels of a same treatment, and to make visualization easier values are normalized to the initial value.

In order to do this I have made a simple script:

```
var1 = c(200:223) # These numbers represent the measured response variable (RV).
var2 = rep(c("A", "A.1", "B", "B.1", "C", "C.1"), each = 1, times = 4) # These are experimental unit identifiers.
var3 = rep(c("37ºC", "45ºC"), each = 6, times = 2) # These are the levels of the treatment (temperature)
var4 = rep(c("First time", "Second time"), each = 12) #These are the times at which the RV was measured.

df = data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4) #Data frame of the vars
```

This is what the data frame looks like:

```
ID  var1  var2 var3     var4
1   200    A 37ºC  First time
2   201  A.1 37ºC  First time
3   202    B 37ºC  First time
4   203  B.1 37ºC  First time
5   204    C 37ºC  First time
6   205  C.1 37ºC  First time

7   206    A 45ºC  First time
8   207  A.1 45ºC  First time
9   208    B 45ºC  First time
10  209  B.1 45ºC  First time
11  210    C 45ºC  First time
12  211  C.1 45ºC  First time

13  212    A 37ºC Second time
14  213  A.1 37ºC Second time
15  214    B 37ºC Second time
16  215  B.1 37ºC Second time
17  216    C 37ºC Second time
18  217  C.1 37ºC Second time

19  218    A 45ºC Second time
20  219  A.1 45ºC Second time
21  220    B 45ºC Second time
22  221  B.1 45ºC Second time
23  222    C 45ºC Second time
24  223  C.1 45ºC Second time
```

The idea for normalization is to compare the values of the `second time` with those of the `First time` for the same `var3`. So for example, compare ID13 with ID1, and ID1 with ID1.

```
df_37 = subset(df, var3 %in% "37ºC") #Subset df by value in var3
df_45 = subset(df, var3 %in% "45ºC")

relat37 = c() #Create vectors where to store normalized numbers for the corresponding var3
relat45 = c()

for (j in df_37$var2) { #Iterate through the values of var2, the identifiers of each VR
  for (i in filter(df_37, var2 == j)[1]) { #Take the first value of the first column of the data frame if the condition is met
  }
  result = (i/i[1]) #divide the values of the second time by those of the first time.
  relat37 = append(relat37, result) #append the results.
}
for (j in df_45$var2) {
  for (i in filter(df_45, var2 == j)[1]) {
  }
  result = (i/i[1]) 
  relat45 = append(relat45, result)
}
```

When calling the storage variables `relat37´ or ´reltat45´ I get the initial var2 normalized to itself, and the second time normalized to its first time value for the same var2. Then it goes onto the next var2.:

```
[1]  1.0 13.0  1.0  7.0  1.0  5.0  1.0  4.0  1.0  3.4  1.0  3.0  1.0 13.0  1.0  7.0  1.0  5.0  1.0  4.0  1.0
[22]  3.4  1.0  3.0
```

The problem is that for some reason it repeats the answers twice, so instead of 12 normalized values I get 24.

**First Question** Is there a way to make a for loop that doesn't require me to make 2 new data frames and 2 separate for loops? I just want a single for loop to do what needs to be done for every level of treatment. In this case there are only two, but I usually work with 6 or more and code gets too long.

**Second Question** Why am I getting 24 results? The second 12 results are just the first 12 repeated. How do I only get the 12 results normalized to each var2´s?

Comment: Are you using any packages? What is the function `filter`? You might want to run `?filter` and check out the description.

Comment: I used dplyr package to filter, but the for loops are my own

Comment: `filter(df_37, var2 == j)[1]` is still a data.frame, with one column. Your loop will only run once. You are saying,  For each column in my one-column data.frame.